# regex to find table name from sql query using shell script

Tags: sql, regex, shell

I need to find table name from query and store the table name to variable.

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO CS_POLICY_TERM_PREM_TRANS(SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD)
    VALUES ( ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT\s+INTO\s+(\w+)
```

Take the first match group

Answer (score 0):

> INTO\s+\w+

**please try this.....**